# React-native global variable undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-native

I am pretty new to React-native so go easy on me! :)

I'm creating an app which uses multiple large json objects for its core data which need to be accessible and updatable across multiple components.  I have achieved this but found that data is only visible across components if I force the object to an array. i.e.

```
global.a1['XX']=data.movies; // This works fine
global.a2=data.movies; // This is undefined in other components.
```

It works but I don't understand why so want to understand what's going on before building the app.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sample code is below:

File: global.js

```
var a1 = new Object();
var a2 = new Object();
module.exports = { a1, a2 }
```

File: select.js

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component,PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Text} from 'react-native';
import * as global from './global';
class Select extends Component {
  render() { 
    console.log("a1:"+global.a1['XX'][0].title); // Ok
    console.log("a2:"+global.a2[0].title); // Fails with undefined is not an object
    return ( <Text>{global.a1['XX'][0].title} {global.a2[0].title}</Text>);
}}
export default Select;
```

File: index.android.js

```
var API_URL = 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/in_theaters.json';
var PARAMS = '?apikey=7waqfqbprs7pajbz28mqf6vz&page_limit=2';
import React, { Component,PropTypes } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry,Text} from 'react-native';
import * as global from './global';
import Select from './select';

class test extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {loaded: false};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API_URL+PARAMS)
      .then((response) => { return response.json() })
      .then((responseData) => { return responseData; })
      .then((data) => {
        global.a1['XX']=data.movies;
        global.a2=data.movies;
        this.setState({loaded: true});
      })
      .done();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) { return ( <Text>Loading...</Text> );}
    console.log("a1:"+global.a1['XX'][0].title); // This works
    console.log("a2:"+global.a2[0].title); // This works
    return ( <Text><Select/></Text> );
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => test);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one case you are modifying an existing variable (by reference), in the other you're modifying the local value assignation.

When you `import * as global from './global'` you're effectively creating a local object pointing to the values exported from `./global`, a bit as if you did:

```
let global = {
    a1: {},
    a2: {}
}
```

Then, you're adding to the object defined as `a1` under the property `XX`, this means that you are changing the original object. BUT when you do `global.a2 = ...` you're not changing the existing object, you're replacing the local reference of `a2` to point to something else, that change will not leave your current module and that's why your `select.js` is not aware of your changes.

That being said, you will have problems with React if you change the content of your objects, rather you should be redefining them, but that's another topic you'll discover soon (immutability).

Comment: Thanks FMC, that makes sense but if adding ['XX'] creates a local copy why is the data accessible in the Select component?  Second question, what is the best way to handle objects that need to be updated by multiple components?

Comment: It's not a local copy, it's a local reference to an object, adding the property `XX` to the object keeps the reference to the object and thus modifies the original. Whereas when you override `global.a2` you locally lose the reference to the original object, and therefore do not reflect any change at the source.